# How to model interrelated select boxes?

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I've got a tree-like structure in four interrelated select boxes. The idea is that after selecting `category1` it displays valid options in `category2`, and so on for `category3` and `category4`. This part of a form can repeat itself more than once.

An example: the user can have as many vehicles as it want. First category is type of vehicle (truck, car, etc), second is brand, third is color and fourth is fuel type.

In Backbone I listened to change events, updating successive select options accordingly. And I'm not sure how to structure this behavior in Ember. An example of an app that works with related DOM elements/events like this would be great.

My first attempt was to create a view for the form, that would listen to `input` (change) events on the select boxes. But the selects are views themselves, and I can't easily refer to the interrelated views. How can I model this?

EDIT:

Solved it in the controller, observing changes in one select to populate the others, like:

```
Ember.ObjectController.extend({
  optionsA: [A1, A2, A3],
  optionsB: [],
  populate: (function() {
    that = this;
    $.map(window.TREE, function(data, groupName) {
      if ($.inArray(that.get('a'), data.as) >= 0) {
        return that.set('optionsB', data.b);
      }
    });
  }).observes('a').on('init')
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You could have an ember's `collectionView` with an `itemViewClass` specified. This `itemViewClass` would be responsible for the show/hide functionality that you need. Each `itemView` should know how to display the initial collapsed category and know to display the extended list of options when that view (category) is clicked on.

If you have a tree-like structure, you could use recursion to model the views and maintain the  parent category - child category relationship.

Comment: Thank you! It seems that `collectionView` is useful for representing array-like structures, but in this case it's always four select boxes, with interrelated behavior. `itemView` number 2 options vary according to what was selected in `itemView` number 1. Do you think it still makes sense?

Comment: It seems they can communicate with each other, here's an example: http://dev.mygrid.org.uk/blog/2013/06/ember-js-dynamic-tree-view/. Will work through it and keep in touch!

Comment: If in the `itemView`'s template I place a `view Ember.Select` I get to the same contexts problem, where I get the two-way binding with the select's model, but not the state of the other select boxes. Not sure how to move on.

Comment: So I connect them through the controller, tomorrow I'll write detailing how I did it. Thank you for your answer!